# Disable features

Tags: users, menu, restricted-access

I have a question here I created a new user account and I want to disable some of the features in the menu so that the user can't have access too like the settings and what not how can I do that

Comment: If you make them a standard user, they won't be able to change any system-wide settings

Comment: Well I don't want users to have access to anything beside firefox and application that allows users to create documents and edit it